# Error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member 'ReactNode', 'DetailedHTMLProps', 'HTMLAttributes', 'SyntheticEvent', 'HTMLProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, namespaces, electron

In my react-typescript-electron project I have:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
  "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0"
 },
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^17.0.1",
   "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
 }
```

This is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
 }
```

I'm getting these error messages:

For this code:

```
import React from 'react';
type Props = React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement, HTMLDivElement>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member 'HTMLProps'.
type Props = React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement, HTMLDivElement>
```

For this code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
interface Props {
summary: React.ReactNode;
  children: () => React.ReactNode;
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
 error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member 'ReactNode'
 summary: React.ReactNode;

 error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member 'ReactNode'
 children: () => React.ReactNode;
```

For this code:

```
 import React from 'react'
 type Value = React.ReactElement
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member 
'ReactElement'
```

For this code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const onToggle = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member 
'SyntheticEvent'
```

For this code:

```
import React from 'react';
type Props =  
React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, 
HTMLDivElement>
```

I get these errors:

```
error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member  
'DetailedHTMLProps'
```

For this code:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
export default function LogLink({ v, children }: Props) {
  function onClick(e: React.SyntheticEvent) {
```

I get this error:

```
error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member 
'SyntheticEvent'
```

Looking forward to your kind help.

Comment: Can you share your code?. As I know they're only data type.

Comment: @ttquang1063750 I updated my post with all the relevant code. Thank you for helping

Comment: Can you remove `node_modules & package-lock.json` and reinstall it again?. Because I can see these properties in `@types/react`. Here is a link to check your type https://unpkg.com/@types/react@17.0.0/index.d.ts

Comment: @ttquang1063750 Removed node_modules and package-lock.json -> yarn -> yarn start. But again the problem persists

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the guys in Typescript Discord Group I discovered that declaring react and react-dom in modules.d.ts interferes with the types definition.
After removing these definitions in modules.d.ts all these errors disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Just do this and go ahead if your Eslint can handle.
// any: means children can have any type

```
{
    children: any
}
```